# Split debug variable output into two separate variables in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am using below code snippet where image details would be printed:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    image_name: "{{ load.results|map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list }}"

- debug:
    var: image_name
```

Output:

```
TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xx.xx.xx.xx]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xx.xx.xx.xx] => {
  "image_name": [
    [
        "Loaded image(s): localhost/cim:v1.5"
    ],
    [
        "Loaded image(s): localhost/cim:v1.8"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Is there a way I can store the image name and tag in two separate variables under `set_fact` itself or in any other form so I can reuse those 2 variables for the next task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`regex_findall`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) filter in order to achieve this.

The regex used here is `(\S*):(\S+)`. <sup>*if needed, more explanation on it can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/g6yxjV/5)*</sup>

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    load:
      results:
        - stdout_lines:
          - "Loaded image(s): localhost/cim:v1.5"
        - stdout_lines:
          - "Loaded image(s): localhost/cim:v1.8"
      
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        images: "{{ images | default([]) + item | regex_findall('(\\S*):(\\S+)') }}"
      loop: "{{ load.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | flatten }}"
  
    - debug:
        msg: "This image repository is `{{ item.0 }}` and its tag is `{{ item.1 }}`"
      loop: "{{ images }}"
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Loaded image(s): localhost/cim:v1.5)
ok: [localhost] => (item=Loaded image(s): localhost/cim:v1.8)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['localhost/cim', 'v1.5']) => {
    "msg": "This image repository is `localhost/cim` and its tag is `v1.5`"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['localhost/cim', 'v1.8']) => {
    "msg": "This image repository is `localhost/cim` and its tag is `v1.8`"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick support..Now i am able to fetch the corresponding image id

    TASK [debug] *********************
    ok: [xx.xx.xx.xx] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "stdout": "v1.5 124715a6d46f",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "v1.5 124715a6d46f"
                ]
            },

How can i fetch get only the image id corresponding to tag?

Comment: i was trying this but getting error:
    - set_fact:
       image_id: "{{ results.stdout | regex_findall('(^v[0-9].* )([0-9a-z]*)') }}"


TASK [set_fact] **************
fatal: [10.10.6.83]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ results.stdout | regex_findall('(^v[0-9].* )([0-9a-z]*)') }}): expected string or buffer"}

Comment: Most likely because your `results` is coming from a loop so you will have a list of `stdout` and not a simple string.

Comment: ok, now i am performing this:
    - set_fact:
       image_id: "{{ image_id | default([]) + item | regex_findall('(\\S*[a-z0-9])[[:space:]](\\S*)') }}"
      loop: "{{ imagestatus.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | flatten }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "image tag is `{{ item.0 }}`"
      loop: "{{ image_id }}"
But not getting image_id and debug o/p
TASK [set_fact] *****************
ok: [localhost] => (item=v1.5 124715a6d46f) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "image_id": []
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "v1.5 124715a6d46f"
}